# Mysql Max() built in function

Tags: mysql, max

I am new to mySQL, and I want to ask what is the problem of this sql statement when I want to find the maximum Life Expectancy of a country

```
SELECT Name, Max(LifeExpectancy) From world.country;
```

This is result:

[image]

However, when i type the SQL below and do sorting, the maximum LifeExpectancy is not the column I expect.

```
SELECT * From world.country Order By LifeExpectancy Desc;
```

[image: abc]

So what is the problem of my first query?

I could get what I expect from this query.

```
Select continent, name, max(LifeExpectancy) As max
From statworld.country
Group By name
Order By max Desc
Limit 1;
```

You can download the sample world database from here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first query, the column `name` is not included in an aggregate function nor a group by, so MySQL choose a random value for it. Thats why you get incorrect results. From the Mysql doc for [Group by handling](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html):

> If [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) is disabled, a MySQL extension to the use of
>   GROUP BY is to permit the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY
>   list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not
>   functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL to
>   accept the preceding query. In this case, ***the server is free to choose
>   any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values
>   chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want***.

You will except the same behavior with the values returned from the column `continent` in your second query:

```
Select continent, name, max(LifeExpectancy) As max
From statworld.country
Group By name
Order By max Desc
Limit 1;
```

You should follow the recommended standard way which other RDBMS (like Oracle and SQL Server) follows, which never use a column without a group by nor an aggregate function when use a `GROUP BY`. So, you should include the column `continent` in a group by or with an aggregate function to get the right values:

```
Select continent, name, max(LifeExpectancy) As max
From statworld.country
Group By name, continent
Order By max Desc
Limit 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need an aggregation for this query at all.  The correct query in MySQL would be:

```
Select continent, name, LifeExpectancy
From statworld.country
Order By LifeExpectancy Desc
Limit 1;
```

(It would be quite similar in other databases.  The change would be to `limit`.  The ANSI standard formulation is `fetch first 1 row only`.)

If you could have ties and you want all the countries, then use:

```
select sc.continent, sc.name, sc.LifeExpectancy
from statworld.country sc
where sc.LifeExpectancy = (select max(sc2.LifeExpectancy) from statworld.country sc2);
```